# ESP32 and FTDI USB to UART wiring

Tags: usb, uart, serial, esp32

I'm designing something like a stream deck. How would I wire a ESP32-WROOM-32D to the f230x? I have already connected the RX and TX but I don't know what to do with the RTS, CTS, and CBUS pins. Also how would I communicate with software and program the esp32 using this?

Comment: Welcome! What does the datasheet or application notes for the IC say?

Comment: @winny It has a description of the pins. Seems like the CBUS pins arent needed. But I still don't know what the RTS and CTS pins connect to.

Comment: Why do you think they need to be connected? What would you do with them?

Comment: If you want to use this FTDI to change the firmware follow the circuit of the esp-prog,

Comment: https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-at/en/latest/esp32/Get_Started/Hardware_connection.html

Comment: You should consider using the ESP32-S3 instead, it's a newer version of the ESP32 and has all features (and more) except for Bluetooth Classic. Instead of Bluetooth Classic, it has BLE. The only thing you'll lose is the ability to do Bluetooth audio with A2DP (not sure if required by your project). 

The benefit of using the S3 is that it has a built-in USB controller which can be used for programming and debugging. This is easier to implement and saves on BOM.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use this FTDI to change the firmware follow the circuit of the esp-prog. (it uses two transitors to control boot and enable)

Now you can use any software that expects an ESP-prog (or expects an ESP32 module that uses the same protocol) to program your device.

There's an application note on the Espressif web site, there's lots of good information there, dive in and have a look around.